# Wrong div with styles in css

Tags: html, css

I'm making one module for my site and it's on the subject of logic gates but it doesn't matter. On the page I have the whole module attached to the div id = "module" which I have defined in css and the module should fit nicely into the div and there should be such a fragment but somehow the styles do not listen and I don't know what to do with it. I did everything by scrolling manually by pixels but still non-functional. Thank you in advance for your help.

**CSS Code:**

```
#operator{
    display: inline; 
    width: 80px; 
    max-width: 80px;
    background: transparent; 
    border: 0;
    font-size: 30px; 
    text-align: center; 
    float: left;
}
#equal{
    width: 36px;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 55px;
    display: inline; 
    float: left; 
    background: transparent; 
}
.bulb{
    background-image:url(assets/zarovka_off.png); 
    background-size: 100%; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 80px; 
    margin-top: 40px;
    float: left;
}
.switch {
    background-image:url(assets/switch_off.png); 
    background-size: 100%; 
    width: 76px; 
    height: 76px; 
    margin: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#module {
    background-color: #04c4d911;
    border-left: 6px solid #04C4D9;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="module">
    <div id="boolean">
        <div id="0" class="switch react-to-dark" onClick="toggle_switch(0);"></div> 
            <select class="react-to-dark" id="operator" onChange="show_result();">
                <option value="AND">AND</option>
                <option value="OR"> OR</option>
                <option value="EOR">EOR</option>
                <option value="NOT">NOT</option>
            </select> 
        <div id="1" class="switch react-to-dark" onClick="toggle_switch(1);"></div> 
        <div class="react-to-dark" id="equal"> = </div> 
        <div id="result-logic" class="bulb"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Sample error:**

[image]

**Example of how it should be in div id = "module":**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the correct CSS file is being served to your page (dev tools in your browser will help you with this).

Comment: Yes, the css file is displayed correctly, but I don't know how to modify it so that it is like in the example of what is under the code.

Comment: Could it be a mistake, for example, that I have there in the css to background-image?

Comment: I don't know how else to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all elements inside your **module** are either inline or float. Elements with float property do not effect size of parent components. I would strongly recommend learning **flexbox** or grid, these are main modern ways how to do layouts (float is very old and limited - there is no reason to use it).

If you would redo your layout using flexbox you wouldn't have any problems. As a quick hack you can just add some height manually to your module element.

```
#module {
    background-color: #04c4d911;
    border-left: 6px solid #04C4D9;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 300px;
}
```